# Printing from other thread when waiting for input()

Tags: python-3.x, console-application, windows-console

I am trying to write a shell that needs to run socket connections on a seperate thread. On my testings, when `print()` is used while `cmd.Cmd.cmdloop()` waiting for input, the print is displaying wrong.

```
from core.shell import Shell
import time
import threading


def test(shell):
    time.sleep(2)
    shell.write('Doing test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    shell = Shell(None, None)

    testThrd = threading.Thread(target=test, args=(shell,))

    testThrd.start()

    shell.cmdloop()
```

When the above command runs, here is what happens:

```
python test.py
Welcome to Test shell.  Type help or ? to list commands.

>>asd
*** Unknown syntax: asd
>>[17:59:25] Doing test
```

As you can see, printing from another threads add output after prompt `>>` not in a new line. How can I do it so that it appears in a new line and prompt appears?

Comment: I can't find any documentation on `core.shell`, but if you could redirect the output of `Shell`, then you could rather easily implement a manage stdout.... it just depends on what the module supports.

Comment: It's a custom created module that inherits `cmd.Cmd` class. https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do, is redirect `stdout` from your `core.shell.Shell` to a file like object such as [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO). You would also redirect the output from your thread into a different file like object.

Now, you can have some third thread read both of these objects and print them out in whatever fashion you want.

You said `core.shell.Shell` inherits from `cmd.Cmd`, which allows redirection as a parameter to the constructor:

```
import io
import time
import threading

from core.shell import Shell

def test(output_obj):
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Doing test', file=output_obj)

cmd_output = io.StringIO()
thr_output = io.StringIO()
shell = Shell(stdout=cmd_output)

testThrd = threading.Thread(target=test, args=(thr_output,))
testThrd.start()

# in some other process/thread
cmd_line = cmd_output.readline()
thr_line = thr_output.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's quite difficult. Both your threads are sharing the same stdout. So the output from each of those threads are concurrently sent to your stdout buffer where they are printed in some arbitrary order.

What you need to do is coordinate the output from both threads, and that's a tough nut to crack. Even `bash` doesn't do that!

That said, maybe you can try using a `lock` to make sure your threads access `stdout` in a controlled manner. Check out: http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Comment: I thought of adding a `do_print()` to the `Shell` class but that will expose print command in shell. using `queue` will not work either because `input()` is blocking the main thread.